# GO button does nothing (AIML rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, aiml

[image: Console tab]

[image: Network tab]

I have installed programr. I followed tutorial from this site http://dreamingechoes.github.io/bot/ruby/rails/conversational-bot-ruby-on-rails/

bot.rb

```
require 'programr'

brains = Dir.glob("lib/bot/*")

BOT = ProgramR::Facade.new
BOT.learn(brains)
```

application_controller.rb

```
def ask_bot
  reaction = BOT.get_reaction(params[:query])
  render json: { response: reaction.present? ? reaction : "I don't have an answer to that"  }
end
```

bot.aiml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <aiml version="1.0" xmlns="http://alicebot.org/2001/AIML-1.0.1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://alicebot.org/2001/AIML-1.0.1 http://aitools.org/aiml/schema/AIML.xsd">

<category>
  <pattern>Hello *</pattern>
  <template>
    Hey, how can I help you?
  </template>
</category>

<category>
  <pattern>*bye</pattern>
  <template>
    Always here for you!
  </template>
</category>

<category>
  <pattern>What payment methods do you accept?</pattern>
  <template>
    We accept Visa, MasterCard and American Express.
  </template>
</category>

</aiml>
```

view:

```
<div class="alert alert-info">
  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
    <strong>Info!</strong> Type something on the text input and hit the <strong>GO</strong> button to get a response.
</div>

<div class="bs-callout bs-callout-info bot-response hide" id="callout-alerts-no-default">
 <h4>Bot says:</h4>
 <p id="bot-response"> </p>
</div>

<div class="row home-row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input id="query" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Say something to the bot...">
     <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button id="ask" class="btn btn-default" type="button">GO</button>
     </span>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

application.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#ask').on('click', function(event) {
    $.ajax({
    url: '/ask_bot',
    type: 'json',
    method: 'get',
    data: { query: $('#query').val() },
    success: function(data) {
    $('.bot-response').removeClass('hide');
    $('#bot-response').html(data['response']);
    $('#query').val('');
   }
  });
 });

});
```

If i copy a pattern and paste in the form, the GO button does nothing. Please help...thanks!

Comment: Is there something in the browser console?, the network tab?, the rails server when you hit the button to make the request?

Comment: dont get what you mean buddy

Comment: oh i get...not sure though

Comment: I meant, that if you make an AJAX request, you could see in the browser console if there are errors, can you?

Comment: let me check that right away

Comment: two errors: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null    Uncaught Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether

Comment: That's when you click the button?, have you integrated jQuery? what does the rails server in the terminal print?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146569/discussion-between-johnnydevv-and-sebastian-palma).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably what you'll have to use is the `DOMContentLoaded` in order to check when the DOM has finished loading, this way you can wrap the listener for the `#ask` button and the AJAX function, without having to modify your "requires" in the `application.js` file, nor to have to include them as script tags in your views.

You could try with something like:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  ...
});
```

And inside to put your JS code, which would remain as:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  $('#ask').on('click', function(event) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/ask_bot',
      type: 'json',
      method: 'get',
      data: { query: $('#query').val() },
      success: function(data) {
        $('.bot-response').removeClass('hide');
        $('#bot-response').html(data['response']);
        $('#query').val('');
      }
    });
  });

  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

Also you could add the specific `custom.js` for the specific controller and action in which is being used, that's the reason of the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null` error, because such elements `barChart`  and `barChart2` are in the `back_office#index`.

Comment: but the "Bot says" is not hidden on page load

Comment: i want to to appear when i ask a question

Comment: Do you mean the `div#callout-alerts-no-default`? Something faster would be to hide it when the dom has been loaded, then show it when the ajax has been succeded, something like [this](https://gist.github.com/vnhnhm/57d4a4d450d829e0e7e7d1b1b5183647).

Comment: did that and it worked but the chat bot is not working again

Comment: Then instead hidding it with jQuery, apply a css class with display:none as value, then on the success ajax callback, remove that class.

Comment: Hey if you know something about mailgun, please look up my recent question...Thanks!!!